# Getting error that Call to undefined function model() When I load to controller in CI framework

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I just now learning codeigniter and this is my

model `second_con.php`

```
class second_con extends CI_Model 
{  //CI version 3.0

public function second_mod() 
{

    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM subdepartment');

    if($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {

        foreach($query->result() as $rows)
        {
             $datas[]  = $rows;
        }
        return $datas;
    }
   }
   }
```

controllers `second.php`

```
class second extends CI_Controller {  

public function index() {

    $this->load-model('second_con'); //line 7

    $this->load->view('home1');
}
}
```

after this when I try to view this page. It showing error as follows. anyone can find out where I made mistake?

> **A PHP Error was encountered**
>
> *Severity: Error*
>
> *Message: Call to undefined function model()*
>
> *Filename: controllers/second.php*
>
> *Line Number: 7*
>
> *Backtrace:*

Comment: Your class name of model should be `class Second_con extends CI_Model` and filename `Second_con.php` codeigniter 3 need first letters to be upper case in controllers and models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are **missing `>` in here `load-model`**

This should be

```
$this->load-model('second_con'); # wrong
```

change to this

```
$this->load->model('second_con'); # correct
```